# Weblogic doesn't close files (but does close connections)

Tags: java, sockets, weblogic, cxf, aix

Dears,

we're running into a 'too many open files' issue.

We've made some progress but the issue is still there...

We use cxf on weblogic on aix.

relevant cxf configuration:

```
<http-conf:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
    <http-conf:client Connection="close" />
</http-conf:conduit>
```

When executing this code:

```
        for(int i=0;i<1300;i++){
            response = callService(request).call();
        }
```

(we don't intend to use this code in production but it's to troubleshoot the issue)

-> the first run succeeds;

-> the second run exposes the problem

output of:

```
   netstat| wc -l
```

first showed that too many sockets remained open (hence the cxf config change)

now the open sockets remain stable +- 400 lines where before the config change >1000

but...

```
lsof 2> /dev/null|grep TCP|wc -l
```

exposes the issue we run into for the present moment

the number of open sockets is stable (so sockets get closed) but the number of open files doesn't...

from 319 just after managed server boot until +-1688 when following exception is raised:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: NullPointerException invoking https://tst-cjcsr.just.fgov.be/cjcs-cg-ws/1.0-rc2/: null
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:158)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy302.requestCriminalRecord(Unknown Source)
    at be.fgov.just.cjr.application.dossier.DossierBean$1.call(DossierBean.java:226)
    at be.fgov.just.cjr.application.dossier.DossierBean$1.call(DossierBean.java:222)
    at be.fgov.just.cjr.application.dossier.DossierBean.callService(DossierBean.java:153)
    at be.fgov.just.cjr.application.dossier.DossierBean.search(DossierBean.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:329)
    at org.jboss.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:342)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstPropertySuffix.invoke(AstPropertySuffix.java:58)
    at org.jboss.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:96)
    at org.jboss.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at be.fgov.just.cjr.application.authentication.UserbeanEnforceFilter.doFilter(UserbeanEnforceFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at be.fgov.just.cjr.application.authentication.openam.OpenAmPingFilter.doFilter(OpenAmPingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at be.fgov.just.cjr.application.authentication.openam.OpenAmReverifyFilter.doFilter(OpenAmReverifyFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at be.fgov.just.cjr.application.authentication.openam.OpenAmSessionFilter.doFilter(OpenAmSessionFilter.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3748)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3714)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2283)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2182)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1491)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:263)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: NullPointerException invoking https://tst-cjcsr.just.fgov.be/cjcs-cg-ws/1.0-rc2/: null
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor108.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:527)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1346)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1335)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:632)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:572)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:481)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:136)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:459)
    at weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpsURLConnection.java:37)
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:1038)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.getResponseCode(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:266)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.doProcessResponseCode(HTTPConduit.java:1550)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1579)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1520)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1317)
    ... 66 more
```

if more info is to be provided, just ask,

any aid in troubleshooting this issue is greatly appreciated,

restarting the managed server 'solves' the problem but this is no option in production...

TIME_WAIT is set to 1 (15 seconds) so no solution there...

S.

**edit:**

one partial solution is described [at DZone](https://dzone.com/articles/too-many-open-files-case-study); indeed:

```
ulimit -S -n
```

outputs 2000 and

```
procfiles 15728790 | grep rlimit
```

outputs

```
Current rlimit: 2000 file descriptors
```

We're implementing their solution now (add ulimit -S -n 65536 to the end of resetFd()) but the root cause (socket leak) is still not solved :-/

Any help still greatly appreciated...

S.